# pythonのwebスクレイピングでタグのclassが入っていないタグを収集するには

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

code：

```
blok[0].find_all('span')
```

out

```
[<span>(11/20 11:46)</span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span>(11/20 11:04)</span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span>(11/20 10:49)</span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span>(11/20 10:45)</span>,
 <span>(11/20 08:58)</span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span>(11/20 07:43)</span>,
```

Comment: pythonのwebスクレイピングの方法はたくさんあります。質問者さんの質問内容だけではそのどれを、どのように使用しているのか分からないので、回答は難しいと思いますよ。

Comment: 解決済みなので, BeautifulSoup だと判断しタグ付けました。が, 似たような別のライブラリーが存在しないとも限らないので(質問者さんの方から)質問内容もしくはタグで記したほうがよいです

Comment: まず[早わかりツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour), [ヘルプセンター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help), そして [質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)なども目を通しておくとよいかもです。
この質問「pythonのwebスクレイピングでタグのclassが〜」に対して, (このコメントの)現在 5 件の回答があり, そのうちの 3つは本当の回答で, あとの 2つの回答には質問者さんが投稿した 続きの質問？ と どれかの回答に対するコメントが「回答のひとつ」として投稿されています。コメントにするなら正しくコメントを付け直したほうがよいでしょうし, 追加の質問？は削除したほうがよいでしょう(削除だけなら管理者でもできるかもだが)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

そのサンプルなら HTML パーサーを使わずにただ文字列正規表現で検索するだけでよさそう

```
import re

blok = ['''
<span>(11/20 11:46)</span>
<span class="PhotoIcon"></span>
<span>(11/20 11:04)</span>
<span class="PhotoIcon"></span>
<span>(11/20 10:49)</span>
<span class="PhotoIcon"></span>
<span>(11/20 10:45)</span>
<span>(11/20 08:58)</span>
<span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
<span>(11/20 07:43)</span>
''']
print(re.findall('<span>.*</span>', blok[0]))
```

実行結果

```
['<span>(11/20 11:46)</span>', '<span>(11/20 11:04)</span>', '<span>(11/20 10:49)</span>', '<span>(11/20 10:45)</span>', '<span>(11/20 08:58)</span>', '<span>(11/20 07:43)</span>']
```

Answer (score 0):

たぶん BeautifulSoup かと思うので

```py
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...:
   ...: html = '''<block>
   ...:  <span>(11/20 11:46)</span>,
   ...:  <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
   ...:  <span>(11/20 11:04)</span>,
   ...:  <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
   ...:  <span>(11/20 10:49)</span>,
   ...:  <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
   ...:  <span>(11/20 10:45)</span>,
   ...:  <span>(11/20 08:58)</span>,
   ...:  <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
   ...:  <span>(11/20 07:43)</span>,
   ...: '''
   ...:

In [2]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
   ...: block = soup.block
   ...: block.find_all('span')
   ...:
Out[2]:
[<span>(11/20 11:46)</span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span>(11/20 11:04)</span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span>(11/20 10:49)</span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span>(11/20 10:45)</span>,
 <span>(11/20 08:58)</span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span>(11/20 07:43)</span>]

In [3]: block('span', class_=True)
Out[3]:
[<span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>,
 <span class="PhotoIcon"></span>]

In [4]: block('span', class_=False)
Out[4]:
[<span>(11/20 11:46)</span>,
 <span>(11/20 11:04)</span>,
 <span>(11/20 10:49)</span>,
 <span>(11/20 10:45)</span>,
 <span>(11/20 08:58)</span>,
 <span>(11/20 07:43)</span>]

In [5]:
```

---

**追記**
ちなみに `block('span', class_=False)` は
`block.find_all('span', class_=False)` の記述でも可能 (短縮してるだけ)

Comment: spanタグを省くってことです！
＜li＞以外を省くことです！

Answer (score 0):

> class が入っていないタグを収集する

CSS セレクタの場合。

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

html = '''
<span>(11/20 11:46)</span>
<span class="PhotoIcon"></span>
<span>(11/20 11:04)</span>
<span class="PhotoIcon"></span>
<span>(11/20 10:49)</span>
<span class="PhotoIcon"></span>
<span>(11/20 10:45)</span>
<span>(11/20 08:58)</span>
<span class="PhotoIcon"></span>
<span>(11/20 07:43)</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
elms = soup.select('span:not([class])')
pprint(elms)

#
# [<span>(11/20 11:46)</span>,
#  <span>(11/20 11:04)</span>,
#  <span>(11/20 10:49)</span>,
#  <span>(11/20 10:45)</span>,
#  <span>(11/20 08:58)</span>,
#  <span>(11/20 07:43)</span>]
```

Comment: BeautifulSoupの確認をすべきかと思いますよ。

Comment: そのままコピペをしましたが、エラーが出てきて、
できていません。

Comment: @ytk064 こちらの環境は Python 3.10.6/BeautifulSoup 4.11.1 です。具体的にどの様なエラーが発生しているのでしょうか？(解決済みなのでご返事なさらなくても構いません)

Comment: エラーではなく、text抽出のみを取得したいのです！
たとえば、<span>タグのみを削除。

Comment: コード
<li class="business" id="g_ASQCP5DZ2QCPULFA00L"><a href="/articles/ASQCP5DZ2QCPULFA00L.html">第２次補正予算案の基金、過去最高の8.9兆円　無駄の温床と批判も<span class="Time"></span><div class="icons">
</div>
<span class="CountTwitter"><img alt="ツイッター" src="//www.asahicom.jp/images/icon_twitter.gif">
<span id="g_t_ASQCP5DZ2QCPULFA00L">0</span></img></span>
<span class="CountFacebook"><img alt="フェイスブック" height="14" src="//www.asahicom.jp/css/images/icon_facebook_logo.png" width="14"/>
<span id="g_f_ASQCP5DZ2QCPULFA00L">0</span></span>
</a></li>

Comment: 第２次補正予算案の基金、過去最高の8.9兆円　無駄の温床と批判も

Comment: エラー云々は本件の質問に対して行ったものです。@ytk064 さんが回答欄に投稿した新規の質問？に対してではありません。

Answer (score 0):

わかりやすい回答、あありがとうございました。

sopu.find_all('div',True)でするのは、とても良かったです。

Comment: 役に立った回答への返信は、回答の下にある「コメントを追加」からコメントしてください。

Comment: どういう意味ですか？
Teueにすると、必要な箇所も消えます。

Answer (score 0):

pythonのwebスクレイピングで不要タグを出力しない方法を教えてください。
例
IN：blok.find_all('li')
out：**<a href="/articles/ASQCP5DZ2QCPULFA00L.html"*>第２次補正予算案の基金、過去最高の8.9兆円　無駄の温床と批判も***

0
 
 0
 ,

Comment: 当サイトはスレッド式の掲示板ではないため、こちらは **新しい質問** として質問し直してください。